# How to add item template to the project application using C# coding (Visual Studio 2022)?

Tags: c#

I need to add the Item Template which I Created to the project application using c# VSIX Extension wizard Project   in Visual Studio

I try to add the Item Template to the Project application by C# coding using Wizard Extension in Visual Studio

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show us your `/.template.config/template.json` and `/.template.config/ide.host.json`

Comment: In my project there is no .json file .